# Exception Throwing Best Practice

Tags: c#, exception

When defining exceptions should you have separate exceptions for every type of error that can occur or a more general exception that can be used for multiple error conditions.

For example lets say that I have a class that processes strings and I want to throw exceptions if a string is not the correct format.

Would I create separate exceptions such as:

StringTooLongException, StringContainsIllegalCharactersException, StringTerminationException

or just create a single exception such as

StringFormatException

and indicate the more specific exception with an error code within the exception?

Comment: When possible, I try to stick to framework-provided exceptions.  For example, in your specific example, I would use this:  [System.FormatException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.formatexception(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Best practice is to use existing exception types that are as close to your exception as possible when you can. If you have to deviate create exceptions are are specific, but not so specific that a developer needs to catch a thousand exceptions. Remember exceptions are expensive! So they should be *exceptional*.

Answer (score 3):

That depends. Can the receiver of the exception take any useful action depending on the type? Then yes, it would be nice to have different types. If all he can do is show the error message to the user, then different .NET types are not useful and if something has no use, it should not be done.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of existing "generic" exception types in the .Net framework, e.g., [System.IO.IOException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ioexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) covers lots of possible IO errors, and [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is used for reporting lots of differents types of Sql error, so I would say it is OK to use a more generic exception type, preferably one that already exists (don't reinvent the wheel).